# sort by nullable property in a n:1 relation

Tags: sorting, grails, groovy

I have the following problem - given just a snippet of the whole domain environment, I'll try to explain it:

I have these two domain classes and want to get a list of studies and sort them by the name of their (current) physician. My problem is, that I don´t know how to do the criteria query with gorm...

```
class Study {    
    Date studydate
    String comment
    static belongsTo = [currentPatient:Patient, originalPatient: Patient, originalPhysician: Physician, currentPhysician: Physician]

    static mapping = {
        columns{
            currentPatient column:'id_patient_current'
            originalPatient column:'id_patient'
            originalPhysician column:'id_physician'
            currentPhysician column:'id_physician_current'
        }
    }
}

class Physician {
    String personname

    static hasMany = [currentStudies: Study, originalStudies: Study]

    static mappedBy = [currentStudies:  'currentPhysician',
                       originalStudies: 'originalPhysician']
}
```

and now the query:

```
def physician = Physician.get(params?.phId)

def studies = Study.withCriteria{
    and{
        maxResults(limit as Integer)
        firstResult(offset as Integer)

        currentPhysician{
            if(physician){
                eq('id', physician.id)
            }    
            order('personname', 'asc')
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that not every study must have a physician - it is possible, that the columns (in the database) - "id_physician" and "id_physician_current" - contain NULL values (the patient did not came from a physician).

via direct sql the query is no problem:

```
select st.id, ph.personname  from study as st left join Physician as ph on ph.ID = st.ID_Physician_Current order by ph.PersonName
```

I am using grails 1.3.7 on a mssql database

Comment: I assume you're getting some sort of exception?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708735/how-do-i-sort-by-a-property-on-a-nullable-association-in-grails

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following query accomplishes what you are asking for.

```
def studies = Study.withCriteria{
    maxResults(limit as Integer)
    firstResult(offset as Integer)
    order('currentPhysician.personname', 'asc')

    if(physician) {
        or {
            eq('currentPhysician', physician)
            isNull('currentPhysician')
        }
    }

    order('currentPhysician.personname', 'asc')
}
```

Maybe not the exact same sql as you expected but if you are worried about that you shouldn't be writing criteria.

Comment: Why are there two "order"´s ?
I am still getting an exception that the property "currentPhysician" can´t be resolved from an Study object:

org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: currentPhysician of: my.project.Study